# Minimum purchase for configurable product

Tags: magento-enterprise

i would like to know if there is a way to have a minimum purchase for configurable product.

Example. We have a soccer club that every child will buy 2 pair of shorts. Can we make it so when a player orders a QTY of 1 they are actually getting 2 pairs of shorts?

I tried minimum shopping qty in inventory tab but it shows qty as 1 by default please note this is for Configurable products

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be as easy as making a plus and minus configurated to increment 2 or deduct 2.

Another choice could be specifying the amount of products of the same.

It could be like this in both choices.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVAIe.jpg

Comment: thanks for that but I would like to show default  qty 2 for some products where i want to sell pair

Comment: Then, you could change by jQuery the default number to 2.
And make that only could insert pair numbers.

More dificults?